# How to retrieve Solr query URL from response object in drupal 7?

Tags: solr, drupal-7

I really want to print the full query for custom solr.

I use this code for getting result from solr :

**Example:**

```
  $solr = apachesolr_get_solr('name_of_solr');
  if($solr->ping()) {
      $params = array(
      'q' => '*',
      'start' => 0,
      'rows' => 20,
      'fl' => 'entity_id',
      );
      $query = new SolrBaseQuery('apachesolr', $solr, $params, '');
      $query->addParam('sort', 'ss_published_date desc'); 
      $query->addFilter('im_field_section', $sc_id);
  }
  $response = $query->search();
```

I am tring to get the full query or URL by

```
dpm($query);//Getting object..
```

**Expected Result:**

```
http://11.11.111.111:8983/solr/tod/select?fl=entity_id&fq=im_field_section:%20174&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=20&sort=ss_published_date%20desc&start=0&wt=json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the full request URL by reading the array key *[request]* from the response object :

```
drupal_set_message(print_r($response, TRUE));

# output :
stdClass Object ( [request] => GET /solr/tod/select?start=0&rows=1&fq=sm_outlet_relations%3A12702&fq=im_field_section%3A44&q=%2A&fl=entity_id&sort=ss_published_date%20desc&wt=json&json.nl=map HTTP/1.0 User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/) Host: my_host [data] => {"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[{"entity_id":582143}]}} [protocol] => HTTP/1.1 [status_message] => OK [headers] => Array ( [content-type] => text/plain;charset=utf-8 [content-length] => 68 ) [code] => 200 [response] => stdClass Object ( [numFound] => 1 [start] => 0 [docs] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [entity_id] => 582143 ) ) ) )
```

Or just :

```
dpm($response->request);

# output :
GET /solr/tod/select?start=0&rows=1&fq=sm_outlet_relations%3A12702&fq=im_field_section%3A44&q=%2A&fl=entity_id&sort=ss_published_date%20desc&wt=json&json.nl=map HTTP/1.0 User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/) Host: my_host
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add echoParams to your solr query, you'll get more details info about your query, and then you can concatenate those to build your original query string.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-TheechoParamsParameter